# How to check a condition on a column list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of column and I want to keep only rows equals to 1 (same condition for all columns) for col1 or col2 or col3.

```
listColumnName=['col1','col2','col3']
myDF[(myDF[listColumnName[0]]==1) | (myDF[listColumnName[1]]==1) | (myDF[listColumnName[2]]==1)]
```

What is the best way if my list of column is very large?

```
myDF[myDF[listColumnName]==1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare all columns filtered by list by subset by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) - check if at least one `True` per row:

```
myDF = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
        'col1':[4,1,4,5,5,4],
        'col2':[7,8,9,1,2,3],
        'col3':[1,3,5,7,4,0],
        'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
        'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (myDF)
   A  col1  col2  col3  E  F
0  a     4     7     1  5  a
1  b     1     8     3  3  a
2  c     4     9     5  6  a
3  d     5     1     7  9  b
4  e     5     2     4  2  b
5  f     4     3     0  4  b

listColumnName=['col1','col2','col3']
df = myDF[myDF[listColumnName].eq(1).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
   A  col1  col2  col3  E  F
0  a     4     7     1  5  a
1  b     1     8     3  3  a
3  d     5     1     7  9  b
```

**Details**:

```
print (myDF[listColumnName])
   col1  col2  col3
0     4     7     1
1     1     8     3
2     4     9     5
3     5     1     7
4     5     2     4
5     4     3     0

print (myDF[listColumnName].eq(1))
    col1   col2   col3
0  False  False   True
1   True  False  False
2  False  False  False
3  False   True  False
4  False  False  False
5  False  False  False

print (myDF[listColumnName].eq(1).any(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```